# persist search filters across multiple routes vue 3 (comp api)

Tags: vue-router, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I'm trying to persist search filters across different routes without the use of Vuex.  I'm using the composition api in vue 3.  I looked into using localStorage with onBeforeRouteLeave and also watchEffect.

Below is the relevant code for adding/removing filters

```
const activeFilters = ref([]);

function addFilter() {
  activeFilters.value.push({
    value: filtered.value,
  });
  filtered.value = "";
}

function removeFilter(idx) {
  activeFilters.value.splice(idx, 1);
}
```

I tried the following, but doesn't seem to work:

```
 onMounted(() => {
   if (localStorage.filters) {
     activeFilters.value = JSON.parse(localStorage.filters);
   }
 });
onBeforeRouteLeave((to, from) => {
   localStorage.filters = JSON.stringify(activeFilters.value);
 });
```

Edit:

I've made some changes that looks like it gets me closer to the solution, but the behavior is inconsistent.  On the route change, sometimes the filter is persisted, sometimes it's not.

```
const activeFilters = ref(JSON.parse(localStorage.filters) || []);
watch(
  () => activeFilters.value,
  (settings) => {
    localStorage.filters = JSON.stringify(settings);
  },
  { deep: true }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue wasn't actually with the localStorage code.  I forgot I had made some changes to the router-view tag and forget to remove them.  For any of those that need help, here's the code I ended up with to persist the search filters across multiple routes.

```
const activeFilters = ref([]);

onMounted(() => {
  console.log(localStorage.filters);
  if (localStorage.filters) {
    activeFilters.value = JSON.parse(localStorage.filters);
  }
});

watch(
  () => activeFilters.value,
  (settings) => {
    localStorage.filters = JSON.stringify(settings);
  },
  { deep: true }
);
```